# How to make a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu open by default when it is inside a collapsed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my dropdown menu open by default when my collapsed navbar is opened. **Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp1d2jz7/) to show my code so far**.

Currently, if you click on the navbar when it's in a collapsed state, two links and a dropdown menu are revealed. You have to click again to open the dropdown menu.

My aim is to make the dropdown menu open by default and hide the `a.dropdown-toggle` element when the collapsed navbar is opened. A visual of how I'd like it to look when the collapsed navbar is opened:

- Link
- Link
- <del>Dropdown</del>
- Action
- Another action
- Something else here
- Separated link
- One more separated link

My first thought was to use `display: none` on `a.dropdown-toggle` but that just hides the whole dropdown menu. Hoping someone can suggest something. I'm open to both jQuery and CSS solutions.

My markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: try adding one more ul with same links of the dropdown and style it show and hide according to width using mediaqueries.

Comment: if you want to shoe it by default :http://jsfiddle.net/mp1d2jz7/2/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that doesn't quite do what I need. I'd like to hide the .dropdown-toggle element as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add css style for responsive mobile display.
paste it into your css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
        position: static;
        background-color:transparent;
        border:0 none;
        box-shadow:none;
        margin-top:0;
        position:static;
        width:100%;
    }
    .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a, 
    .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        padding:5px 15px 5px 25px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a{
        line-height:20px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a{    
        color:#777;
    }
}
```

you can see it in its entirety here : [`Demo jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/paydjo/0g906911/9/)

hope that helps.

Comment: you just need to add a little css like the above into your css file and html structure is not changed.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for that. The `a.dropdown-toggle` element is still showing though?

Comment: i was updating on here : [JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/paydjo/0g906911/7/)

Comment: I was wrong understanding, I'm sorry. 
I have the latest updates: [jsFiddle Update Fix](http://jsfiddle.net/paydjo/0g906911/9/)

Comment: I had problems with this code.. It's nice until you have another link or another dropdown menu after first dropdown, for some reason the another links overlays the dropdown menu above it so its unable to click.. Here is an example in jsFiddle, notice when you hover above the dropdown menu, the last link gets highlighted instead [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybmtmok1/1/)

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs for Bootstrap v3, you can use Javascript to hook on the collapse events:

```
$(function () {
  $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $('#my_dropdown').dropdown('toggle', 'open').hide();
    console.log('shown:', e);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure the result is what you want, because while the "toggle" button is hidden, the submenu is still indented. Instead of trying to bend Bootstrap that much, perhaps a better solution is having 2 menus with the desired structure for each screen size and show one or another based on media queries.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scardine/tw82o88y/

Comment: This works as long as you don't resize the browser at all.  If you click the burger button when the nav is collapsed and then later resize the browser to where the nav is no longer collapsed, the drop menu is then missing from the nav.

Comment: Its open only the last dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a javascript function to your code:

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").hover(            
  function() {
   $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
   $(this).toggleClass('open');        
  },
  function() {
   $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
   $(this).toggleClass('open');       
  }
  );
 });
</script>
```

you can see the example and demo in [dtc-eng](http://dtc-eng.blogspot.co.id/2015/12/dropdown-menu-with-bootsrap.html)

Comment: You should explain why this function addresses the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Just remove `data-toggle="dropdown"`