# Bootstrap navbar dropdown-toggle with link on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dealing with a problem with Bootstrap navbar, where I have multiple dropdowns but I need the actual dropdown-toggles to be links aswell, it works on desktop, but there is a problem with that on mobile, where there is no hover which Im using to show the dropdown.

For example this basic menu:

```
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="link_to_somewhere" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

I am controlling the hover dropdown with JQuery.
I want to have the dropdowns shown on mobile automatically, so you can click all of the links.

I used the solution described here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261254/how-to-make-a-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-open-by-default-when-it-is-inside-a-coll)

Problem with that one is that if you have another link or dropdown under the first one, the second one overlays the dropdown menu above it so you can't click it.

Look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybmtmok1/1/)

When the navbar is collapsed, open it and try to hover over the dropdown menu, you can see that the link underneath is highlighted instead. 
For some reasone the bottom link element gets expanded, and I can't get rid of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I looked into that the other day. The problem is that you mess up the dropdown behaviour. I don't think that is your quest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it messed it up, but on desktop it works fine this way, and I need to have the parent links clickable, also the mobile version looks fine, only if I could click it :) And I don't want to make other approaches such as having the parent link as first link in the dropdown and parent itself being the toggle..

Comment: Okay, for now I have fixed it by removing the 'dropdown-menu' class from the 'ul' on small screens, which does what I wanted.. Its pretty messy solution I think, but it works..